# Prevent save using IResourceDeltaVisitor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, client-server, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to write an eclipse plugin which works like a client to a server. The client will try to interact with the server when a resource tracked by the plugin is modified and the Save button is clicked.

What I intend to implement is to prevent the local save from happening (i.e. retain the file as dirty) until the server interaction is complete and if the interaction is successful.

For this, I have implemented IResourceChangeListener and IResourceDeltaVisitor which triggers the server event on POST_BUILD (instead of POST_CHANGE, because I do not want the local save to happen yet).

```
getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(new MyChangeListener(), IResourceChangeEvent.POST_BUILD);

MyChangeListener#resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
    switch(event.getType()) {
        case IResourceChangeEvent.POST_BUILD:
            event.getDelta().accept(MyresourceVisitor.create());
    }
}

MyresourceVisitor#visit(IResourceDelta delta) {
    switch (delta.getKind()) {
        case IResourceDelta.CHANGED:
            boolean success = interactWithServer(delta.getResource());
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But this would always go ahead and save the resource as well irrespective of the success of the server interaction - How can I prevent the save?

Comment: The resource has already been saved when these events are fired.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your response! I have added some more code to show the call hierarchy. What am I missing in order to achieve my intent?

Comment: You can't do this in the resource change listener because the file has already been saved before the resource change event is created.

Comment: @greg-449 Can you help me with some code / example to show how this might be possible then?

Comment: Do you have your own editor or do you use a generic one? If you have your own editor you can implement the doSave() method.

Comment: @AryeShemesh I use the in-built default editor associated for the file type.

Comment: I don't know of any way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried listening to IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_BUILD events?